# past or present tense?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

I'm wondering whether the boldfaced forms in the follownig should have been changed into the past tense, e.g., "were," "could," and "was."

> M: How was your stay at the hotel?
>
> W: Excellent. The pool was wonderful. And the room was clean.
>
> M: Sounds great. Did you go anywhere else?
>
> W: No. We just stayed there all day. There **are** several good coffee shops in it. We **can** even have meals there. It **is** great, right?

Comment: A side note: it would be more fluent to say "Did you go anywhere else?" (with no **to**)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they should be changed into the past tense. The reason why W used the present tense is that she was stating facts. Facts are always true to the speaker at the time of utterance.

When W said, "there are several good coffee shops in it," it implies she saw good coffee shops when she first stayed at the hotel. And when she left the hotel, the good coffee shops still exist. If she said, "there *were* several good coffee shops in it," it sounds weird because it might mean that all good coffee shops are taken down and are replaced by bad ones.

The follow-up sentences "we can even have meals there" and "it is great" tells more about the fact "there are several good coffee shops in it". They are also facts, so they must be in the present tense.

Edit: As explained by @stangdon, it is wrong to say "we can even have meals there" because W is not in the hotel anymore. It is better to say "we *could* even have meals there" in this context.

Comment: I think it's OK to say "there *are* several good coffee shops" but I think "We *can* even have meals there" sounds wrong, because the stay was in the past.  Clearly she cannot have meals there now, because she is not there, so "We *could* even have meals there" works better.

Comment: @Jimmy Yang Are you a Chinese speaker?

Comment: @stangdon What do you think of the "It **is** great"?

Comment: @Apollyon No, despite having a Chinese last name, I'm not a native Chinese speaker.

Comment: @Apollyon "It is great" sounds okay to me. It depends on what W was referring to. If W refers to her hotel stay, then it is better to use "It *was* great."

Comment: @Apollyon  I agree with Jimmy Yang about the is/was part.  "It **is** great" sounds OK to me because W seems to be describing the hotel.  If she were referring specifically to her stay, she should use **was** because it was in the past.  But "It was great, right?" sounds strange because she should be *telling* M, not *asking* him.

Comment: @stangdon How about "It was great, wasn't it?"

Comment: I thought "right" can be used to ask for the listener's agreement.

Comment: @Apollyon  "It was great, wasn't it?"  sounds even more like W is asking M whether it was great.  Yes, people sometimes use *right*, but it's better used like "You wanted me to buy the *large* eggs, right?"  Otherwise it's a filler word, a meaningless verbal tic like, "So yesterday I went downtown, right?  And I ran into my old friend Jimmy, right?  And we agree to go get lunch together, right?"  It's a way of checking if the listener is still listening, not asking for their agreement.

Answer (score 0):

> W: No. We just stayed there all day. There are several good coffee shops in it. We can even have meals there. It is great, right?

This conversation seems to be about a recent hotel stay and, though the stay is past, it is reasonable to assume that the good coffee shops are still there.  The use of present tense *are* in paragraph 4 should be fine.

The clause

> It is great, right?

however seems to describe more of that stay rather than the presence of coffee shops, hence *was* should be more appropriate.

The clause

> We can even have meals there

is less clear.  Coffee shops' allowing customers to have meals there is a reasonable assumption, but if it is highlighted as if it is a special arrangement, then it could be it, special.  I hence interpret that to also be describing more of that stay and hence suggest *was*.

> There are several good coffee shops in it. We *could* even have meals there. It *was* great, right?